# Creating delay between writing to sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

My NodeJS web application using ExpressJS is receiving data from Android Application .On receiving data we are sending data to another server through TCP/IP socket stream . Everything is working fine but since the data is being sent at very good speed the connections get refused for some of the transactions by server . We need to create delay between API calls or Socket writing so that the connection doesn't refuse . Here is my code

```
  function send(data, tr_id, server_ip, port) {


    var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(port, server_ip, function () {
    try    {     
        console.log('Connected');
        client.write(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Send function error " + error);
    }
    });
    client.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('Received: ' + data);
        //set the flag 1 in tbl_transactions    
        if (data.includes("status='ACK'")) {
            dbConn.query("UPDATE  tbl_transaction set flag='1' where tr_id =" + tr_id, function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err)
                    console.log('error occured in updating flag - ' + err.code + " ,error_description - " + err);
            });
        }
        client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
    });
    client.on('close', function () {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
    client.on('error', function (error) {clearImmediate
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I have tried timers but it wont work any other robust solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sleep function using promises and setTimeout:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a setTimeout around your update query, for 1 second of delay :

```
 setTimeout(function(){
     dbConn.query("UPDATE  tbl_transaction set flag='1' where tr_id =" + tr_id, function (err, rows, fields) {
         if (err)
            console.log('error occured in updating flag - ' + err.code + " ,error_description - " + err);
     });

 }, 1000);
```